# VueJS & v-html: How do I prepend the baseURL to asset links in imported HTML?

Tags: vue.js

Apologies if this explanation isn't super clear. I am new to VueJS and I will do my best to explain my predicament.

I am building an application that imports html from external files into a component using v-html. I achieved that without any problems. However, the html has a bunch of asset urls that start with a /. What I want to do is to ensure that every asset url that starts with a / has a baseURL placed in front of it, converting it from say '/some-folder/some-asset.jpg' to '../../static/some-folder/some-asset.jpg' automatically without me having to programmatically modify the url.

I have tried modifying settings in the configuration file index.js, namely by trying different urls in assetsSubDirectory and assetsPublicPath but without success.

This is an example of a node in the imported html:

```
<picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 768px)"srcset="/media/3974/cover_tablet.jpg">
      <img id="img_20921" src="/media/3973/cover-mobile.jpg" class="img-fluid">
</picture>
```

I am trying to change the src value of:

/media/3974/cover_tablet.jpg

to:

../../static/media/3974/cover_tablet.jpg

by setting a base URL in the vue configuration but it won't prepend ../../static to the url and therefore the app cannot find the relevant asset.

The only way I managed to get this to work is by using JQuery to look for "src:" strings in the imported html and then prepend the baseURL into the link. This isn't at all ideal though and what I really want to achieve is for any link that starts with a "/" to have the apps baseURL prepended to it automatically.

I am starting to wonder if it is even possible for urls in imported html to pick up the apps baseURL value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I was using the webpack template for my project which proved to make this particular issue difficult to work out so I reset my project using the Vue CLI template instead, put all my assets in the public folder and all the links in my imported html were picked up immediately with no fuss and no messing around with webpack configuration.